# How to add and use an additional field in a Jetty users table?

Tags: java, jetty

I need to set a limit on how many items a user can add to an order. I therefore wish to have an additional field in my users table (an integer) specifying that limit. I can add the field easily enough, with an alter table statement, but how can I access the new field in my code?

An alternative solution could be to add several roles, one for each limit I need, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

I'm using Jetty 8.1.5 and JDBCLoginService, and I don't have much experience with Jetty at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users table for the `JDBCLoginService` is not designed for that.

Your requirements have outgrown the role of `JDBCLoginService` (minimal identity store for authentication).

You'll need to establish a custom `LoginService` of your own, that will access the Database schemas of your choice, and then you can reuse that same database via the traditional `JNDI` and `DataSource` access found in Java Web Containers.